# IIS not serving up .dat files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a ASP MVC web application that uses a plugin to load images and points for a 3d application.

When debugging with the the Visual Studio development server the images and the points are served up great...

http://i148.photobucket.com/albums/s19/littleniv/Debugging/local.png

Second image: same url but iis.png

When running in IIS 7 though the .Dat point files do not serve and produce a 404.

I've noticed the caching is marked as private in fiddler, but i don't know what this means.  Can anyone help?

Cheers,

Stu

Answer (score 15):

It's been a while, but I have seen a similar issue in IIS 6.  IIS by default will only serve a file if it is configured to serve it based on the extension and mime type.

Go into the IIS Manager, click on the server, then open up **"MIME Types"** under the IIS Area.  Hit **"Add..."** in the upper right corner (under actions), and type in your extension (**".dat"**) and a mime type (depends on your data; maybe **"application/octet-stream"**?).

[image]

Once you've done that, you should be able to download the files.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I already just did that, but after I've added it it seems to strip off the css stylesheet then throws a error saying i can't add a duplicate mime map, when their isn't an entry in it in the IIS mime types.  Could it be possible the application is setting it somewhere already?

Comment: Another point, i checked the iis logs and it is a 404.3, which i think is definitely a mime type problem..

http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/cc753281(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I'm a bit confused - did you get an error adding the new MIME type, or is this an application error?

Comment: Sorry, I had added it at website level previously and tried to add it at application level.  They mime type is set correctly to application/octet-stream, but i still get the 404.3 and it is still showing in fiddler as text/html charset utf-8

Here is a line from the IIS log

2010-04-22 17:30:00 192.168.1.100 GET /NBPortal/Content/TruViews/Pnt_5_1024.DAT - 80 stu 192.168.1.100 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 404 3 50 2

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue while trying to serve a blazor wasm application.

First try to browse the application locally on the web server. If you see an error similar to image below,

[Network Tab Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh8nK.png)

You can make out that the Requested URL shows, Rejected-By-UrlScan added to the actual URL.

So the url scan is rejecting the .dat file request. To fix this url scan has to be configure to serve dat file types.

Open up UrlScan.ini (I found it in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\urlscan folder)

Find the DenyExtensions section and comment / remove the line starting with .dat

Now you will be able to load .dat files.

Hope, this answers helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Apparently the 404.3 50 error is ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.  Can anyone shed any light?

ALL STOP!!!

I added a static file handler mapping and everything is solved.  Many thanks to Chris for helping me run through some trouble shooting.  I'll mark you as the answer as you are the only one that helped!! Thanks again!!

Eek.  I have multiple accounts on SO... this is going to take some sorting out!

Answer (score 0):

For an Azure web app, the following change to the web.config did the trick, thanks for the Mime type clue:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```